# Seam entity query count is wrong ordered by ManyToOne

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I've got an object mapped with a `ManyToOne` column. When trying to order by a column on the `ManyToOne` joined table, the count and actual results list size are inconsistent.  This allows the user to page beyond the actual last page of results. When Seam's `EntityQuery` renders the SQL to retrieve the list of results it includes that table with a join, But for the `COUNT` SQL it's leaving it out.

In the example SQL below, I'm ordering on table `ETEM_VW_CIN_COURSE`, column `CIN`.

The difference in the SQL comes down to:

```
select
    ...
from
    ETEM.ETEM_INV_INVENTORY eteminvinv0_,
    ETEM.ETEM_UIC etemuic1_,
    ETEM.ETEM_VW_CIN_COURSE etemvwcinc2_ 
where
    ...
order by
  etemvwcinc2_.CIN
```

And:

```
select  
    count(*) as col_0_0_ 
from
    ETEM.ETEM_INV_INVENTORY eteminvinv0_,
    ETEM.ETEM_UIC etemuic1_ 
where   
    ...
```

This only happens when I'm ordering by a column on the `ManyToOne` join. If I remove the *order by* then it looks to work as expected.  Any way to get the SQL and `COUNT` SQL to execute the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by my trying to sort on a joined table, joined on a field which isn't required.  I adjusted my EJBQL so that when I want to sort on that column (stored as orderBy on my component), to only include rows where the foreign key is not null.   That portion looks like this in my WHERE clause:

and ( lower(#{etemInvInventoryList.orderBy}) <> 'cin' or etemInvInventory.crseId is not null )

That forces the EJBQL and CountEJBQL to pull the same set of results.